# И ещё о титулах: дочь титулованного лица

Tags: общие-вопросы

Везде пишут по-разному: где-то, что, например, "графиней" можно называть дочь графа, в других источниках сообщается, что дочери титулованных личностей могут называться исключительно словом "леди". Так как же правильно назвать дочь графа: леди, графиня или молодая графиня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте разбираться...
Я думаю, что исходя из списка достаточно ограничиться английской традицией, хотя в общем-то эти вещи интернациональны по крайней мере в масштабах Европы.

"леди" - вариант беспроигрышный. Любая знатная дама (а в современном языке и не только знатная) имеет право именоваться леди.

Титул графа передаётся только по мужской линии, причем только старшему в роду. Женщины на него не претендуют (кроме отдельных случаев вроде полного отсутствия наследников мужского пола по всем линиям - от первого носителя титула). 
Так как может дочь при живом отце называться графиней?

Молодая графиня - титул неофициальный. Думаю, что вполне сгодится.

В русском языке есть на то особые формы - княжна, боярышна (барышня), царевна и проч... Но вот в отношении заимствованных титулов типа графа, барона или единичного герцога (остальные на нашей земле не прижились вовсе) их использование весьма сомнительно. "Графинишна" встречается как окказионализм.

Answer (score 2):

А вас Англия интересует или Россия? Если Россия - из текста романа "Война и мир" следует: дочь графа можно называть графиней (так называют, например, Наташу Ростову). А вот дочь князя - княжна.

Comment: @Тина, а если речь об Англии, тогда?

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Наверное, есть специальная литература по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Леди (англ. lady), от староанглийского hlǣfdige —"та, кто месит хлеб"
[1]. В утерянном смысловом значении — владеющая секретом приготовления квашеного («кислого») хлеба[источник не указан 406 дней]. В англоязычном мире — подчеркнуто вежливое обращение к женщине. Обозначение «леди» признает высокое место обладательницы титула в обществе, ее светские манеры и элегантный вид. Также аристократический титул в институте британской монархии, употребляемый с именем.
Соответствует обозначениям мужчин: «джентльмен» (стандартное обращение к слушателям — «леди и джентльмены»), «лорд», «сэр» (подробнее см. ниже).
Наименование Our Lady («наша Госпожа») означает Святая Дева (в русском языке имеет эквивалент Божья Мать (Богоматерь)).
Наименование «леди» как часть полного имени в Великобритании используют:
с основной частью титула, например, «леди Маунтбаттен» — женщины, являющиеся в своём праве пэрами Великобритании (наряду с более точными и официальными титулами: «графиня», «маркиза», «виконтесса», «баронесса»; герцогини обычно не называются «леди», а только полным титулом);
с основной частью титула, например, «леди Эссекс» — жёны лиц, имеющих право на полноценный титул «лорд» (пэров Великобритании; наряду с более точными титулами по мужу: «графиня» и т. п.)
с личным именем и фамилией, например, «леди Диана Спенсер» — незамужние дочери герцогов, маркизов и графов;
с фамилией или именем мужа, например, «леди (Рэндольф) Черчилль» — жёны лиц, имеющих право на личный титул учтивости «лорд» (в определённых случаях — сыновья пэров Великобритании; см. подробнее статью титул учтивости);
с фамилией, например, «леди Маккартни» — жёны лиц, имеющих право на титул «сэр» (рыцарей и баронетов).
Вдовы, не вступившие в повторный брак, сохраняют те же титулы, что при жизни мужей (возможно прибавление слова Dowager — «вдовствующая»). Разведённые жёны, не вступившие в повторный брак, используют титул без определённого артикля the (Lady Smith — бывшая жена лорда Smith).
Для жён республиканских глав государств используется (не во всех странах официальное) обозначение «первая леди» (англ. the First Lady).

Comment: У меня чёткий вопрос о дочерях титулованных особ. Этимология, а так же титулы жён меня не интересуют.